# How to find out the average on a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, average

I have a csv file and I'm able to import it into the program. I need to know how to calculate the average on a specific column of the file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order for us to give you good answers, you need to show us what you've tried so far and where your *specific* problems are.  If you're able to read in the file, show us that!  Are you familiar with the `csv` module?  A google search on this topic (reading CSV files with Python) will net you lots of useful examples.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? First the file must be read and the value of the column totaled before calculating the average.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
with open('your_csv.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    if your_file_has_a_header_row:
        next(reader)
    the_numbers = [float(row[col_index_you_want]) for row in reader]
    average = sum(the_numbers) / len(the_numbers)
```

If using Python 3, change the with statement to

```
with open('your_csv.csv', newline='') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split this problem into parts:

1. Read file
2. Seperate out the right column
3. Calculate total
4. Divide by number of rows.

Take one line at a time and you should be fine. Google will help you with the details and you're welcome back to SO when you have specific questions in any of the parts.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get data from column :

```
columnNumber = 42
data = [float(l.split(';')[columnNumber]) for l in open('file.csv', 'r').readlines()]
```

Then compute average:

```
mean = sum(data) / len(data)
```

EDIT : code fix (from Steven Rumbalski)

Comment: -1.  A couple of problems.  It's a csv file so each line needs to be parsed by commas (and possibly quote characters).  Also, you cannot sum a string.  You never convert it to a numeric type.

Comment: You are right. And thank you, I didn't know about csv module.